# PHP Display button if user is an admin

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, admin

With this piece of code below I receive the users that are an admin from the database. A user is an admin if he has the value '1' in the 'admin' row. So I am only able to get the email addresses from all the admins, but how do I make a button that is only accessible for these admin users, so only they can go to an admin panel.

```
$admincheck = $db->prepare("SELECT mail From users WHERE admin = 1");          
$admincheck->execute();
$admin = $admincheck->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($admin as $row) {
     echo $row['mail'];
}
```

Comment: you are already listing rows which is admin so why you need to recheck if its admin or not

Comment: you need to use `session variable in php`. that is what you should search for on google, to point you in the correct direction.

Comment: So how do you know which user is on your site? Are they logged in? If so, add there userid or whatever reference to the query `where` clause. If the query returns a row, the user is admin, if not, he is not admin. The trick is not to find all admins, but to find if the 'current' user (whatever that may be) is admin.

Comment: Every user is able to make an account and login. When the user is logged in he is provided with a login session. How do you check for each user that logs in which specific id he has? Because right now every user that logs in can get to the admin panel

Comment: @GolezTrol it seems like I need to request the info of the user that is currently logged in, and check if the value of the row 'admin' is 1 or not.. do you have any idea how i can get the users info with `$_SESSION `

Comment: I'm missing some context. You already mentioned `$_SESSION`. You know how to use it? Do you have a login system at all? How does it work? Did you build it? I suggestion you update the question with information like that, otherwise I'll be typing a complete tutorial in comments, which I'm not going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create an if statement checking if the admin value returns true > create the button.

```
 <?php if($admin == true){
         echo "<button>Adminpanel</button";
       }
  ?>
```

or

```
 <?php
   if($admin == true){
 ?>

 <button>button</button

 <?php
   }
 ?>
```

Also do a check before loading the page's content if the user is an admin, so nobody can just get there by only entering the url.

In the first example you echo the button to the page, in the second example you just use html as usual.

Comment: Although this is (roughly) true, the problem seems to be that OP doesn't know how to check if a user is admin, so the core problem is how to find out whether to set `$admin` to `true` or to `false` before your code. Unfortunately this is not covered by your answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol do you know how I can get the info (id, mail, password) of a logged in user using $_SESSION?

Comment: @MotambeMarkumbo You should search the files for it. Somewhere the $_SESSION is being initiated or find an example where the check is already being done. When you know what it's called, you can call the value using $_SESSION['example'] .